# matlab dot and cross product of two vectors

Tags: matlab

I don't understand what some behavior in Matlab 2013a, with the functions dot and cross.

I have 2 vectors as a basis of a plane:
v1 = [-0.3134 , 0.0079 , 0.0072]
v2 = [-0.1132 , 1.1473 , 0.1586]

If I compute C = v1xv2 (cross product), then I will have the normal vector of the plane formed by v1 and v2:
C= cross(v1,v2)
C = [-0.0070 , 0.0489 , -0.3587]

But when i probe that this vectors must to be orthogonally, C and v1 are not.

dot(C,v1) = 4.3368e-19
dot(C,v2) = 0

I verify manually the dot product of C dot v1, effectively, is not zero

What is the problem , my version of matlab ? or my computer architecture (Intel I7)?

Comment: well 4.3368e-19 is pretty close to 0 isn't it? It's due to floating-point arithmetic: http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/floating-point-numbers-in-matlab-2/

Comment: this question comes up every single day... read here: [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab).

Comment: Always bear in mind that MatLab aims for computational efficiency in numerical calculations, rather than precision. Still it's pretty much precise, 4e-19 is close enough to 0 in virtually any application. If not, you need to scale, rather than seek this kind of precision

Comment: @thewaywewalk - This as well as `imshow` mixing `double` and `uint8` problems are the two most frequent things people with MATLAB questions ask often when I visit StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry guys, for me zero is very different of 4e-19, for example if you take the log10(4e-19) is approx. -18. for many engineering calculations that can lead to a collapse. Thanks by the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the cross product C and its dot product with v1 and v2 will be contaminated by small amounts of round-off error.  You can estimate the magnitude of such errors with the MATLAB `eps` feature (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), which returns your machine's floating-point precision.  The most meaningful way to test whether a floating point number is "zero" is to compare it to eps, via something like:

```
dot(C,v1)<eps
```